# Jenkins thinks failing junit test is passing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit

One stage in my Jenkins pipeline runs `mvn verify`. My test phase is broken into two execution stages, and in the second stage, one of the junit tests from the first stage is re-run with different parameters. This all works perfectly locally with Maven.

When Jenkins runs this with the same configs, it seems to ignore the repeated test in the second phase. If that test fails, Jenkins reports that all tests pass, even though in the Jenkins console logs I can see that the test did fail.

Is there a Jenkins-friendly way of re-running the same test in two different execution stages?

My Maven `pom.xml` file contains:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- some configs -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>another-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- some configs -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: In Jenkins, is this a Maven job, or a Freestyle job with a Maven build step?

Comment: try other id : <id>default-test</id> to <id>one-test</id>